# Square Grid - (Rotated) Rect intersection - Calculate all intersection cells

Tags: math, grid, geometry

We have Square Grid with a Cell width and height of 1.0

The grid can be of any size, let's say 25x25 for this example.

Now there's a rectangle (or a line with a thickness), that has an arbitrary start and end point, e.g. start point (2.2, 1.0) end point (20.4, 5.5), thickness 1.5. The start and end point are in the center of a rectangle line, hence the thickness expands equally on both sides of the line.

How can one calculate all cell coordinates that this rectangle intersects with?

Answer (score 0):

To enumerate all intersected cells for thin line case, there is method of Amanatides and Woo [A Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm for Ray Tracing](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf).
[Here is](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml) practical implementation.

For thick line you may choose two parallel edges of rectangle and walk through them synchronously by some coordinate (X or Y), at every step getting the whole scanline.

For your case (arbitrary coordinates, probably not exact):

```
bottom left corner is in (2,0) cell, top left in (2,1) cell
(2,0)-(2,1) vertical scanline contains two cells
walk with bottom ray to (3,0), wait until top ray reaches X=3
walk with top ray to (2,2), add this cell to the last scanline
walk with top ray to (3,2)
(3,0)-(3,2) vertical scanline contains three cells
and so on
```